# minimum value from an 2dArray

Tags: python, python-3.x, minimum

I have this array:

```
A = [[30, 80, 50], [44, 60, 41]]
```

How can I get output like:

> min = [30, 60, 41]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
A = [[30, 80, 50], [44, 60, 41]]
print([min(column) for column in zip(*A)])
```

output:

```py
[30, 60, 41]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
A = [[30, 80, 50], [44, 60, 41]]
np.min(A, axis=0) # computes minimum in each row
```

**Output:**

```
array([30, 60, 41])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
A = [[30, 80, 50], [44, 60, 41]]
list(map(min, zip(*A)))
```